# How can I get registered controllers name in angularjs module?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Is there any way that I get regestered controllers name in my angularjs module?
I implement Lazy Loading controller in my sample and I want test my code .

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an IIFE structure like so:

```
(function() {
  angular.module( 'MyApp', [
  'dependency',
]);
```

a controller function would simply look like this:

```
function SomeCtrl($scope, ...) {

};
```

and then at the bottom of your page:

```
angular
  .module('MyApp')
  .controller('SomeCtrl', SomeCtrl)
})();
```

In test cases (e.g. Jasmine), you will be able to access the ctrl by its name.